# How to stop xmlns attribute from being created during svg createElement step

Tags: java, xml, dom, svg, batik

I am trying to add a backing box to a Text label in an SVG document. The process is working ok except that the svg.createElement step is also creating an entry in my XML file like this `xmlns=""`

This entry seems to be causing my SVG file (XML) to not display correctly on my JSVG canvas. If I manually edit the file and remove this entry then the XML displays correctly.

My code snippet is shown below.

```
    if(domElement instanceof SVGOMTextElement) {
          SVGOMTextElement text = (SVGOMTextElement) domElement;
          NodeList tspans = text.getElementsByTagName("tspan");
          for(int i = 0; i < tspans.getLength(); i++){
             Node node = tspans.item(i);
             SVGOMTSpanElement tspan = (SVGOMTSpanElement) node;
             Element backBox = svg.createElementNS(null,"rect");
             backBox.setAttributeNS(null,"id", "backingRect-attx" + String.valueOf(Math.round(tspan.getExtentOfChar(0).getX())) + "atty" + String.valueOf(Math.round(tspan.getExtentOfChar(0).getY())));
             backBox.setAttributeNS(null,"width", String.valueOf(tspan.getComputedTextLength()));
             backBox.setAttributeNS(null,"height", String.valueOf(tspan.getExtentOfChar(0).getHeight()));
             backBox.setAttributeNS(null,"style", "fill:green;fill-opacity:0.5");
             backBox.setIdAttributeNS(null,"id", Boolean.TRUE);

             text.getParentNode().insertBefore(backBox, text);
    }
```

The XML tag that this code generates is shown below,

```
<rect xmlns="" width="59.89038" style="fill:yellow;fill-opacity:0.5"
id="backingRect-attx407atty427" height="16.734436"/>
```

So the question is how can I stop this attribute (`xmlns=""`) from being added to my SVG XML output file?

I've tried to debug through the code but I cant see an attribute "xmlns" created after the line,

Element backBox = svg.createElementNS(null,"rect");

I was trying to execute a removeAttribute step but this didn't work (as I couldn't find a xmlns attribute).

I am using Apache Batik ver 1.8

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xmlns="" namespace declaration is generated because you chose to put your element in the null namespace.

```
Element backBox = svg.createElementNS(null,"rect");
```

If you create your element in the SVG namespace all should be well.

Comment: Hi Michael - your answer worked. I changed the line as you suggested to, 

Element backBox = svg.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","rect");

and the attribute disappeared from my output and not only that but the original problem I was having with the JSVGCanvas not refreshing with my updated Dom is now working. So I am very happy.

Thank you very much for your help. I've been struggling with this for days.